# Default Parameters in Functions - C++

Tags: c++, default-value, function-parameter

If I'm not wrong this kind of declaration may be used to assign default values in a constructor:

```
/* .h */
class FooClass(){

   private:
     int* data;
     int depth, rows, columns;
     char* desc;

   public: 
     ... 
}

/* .cpp */
FooClass::FooClass()
    : data(NULL), depth(0), rows(0), columns(0), desc(NULL)
{
     //whatever constructor does...
}
```

but it is not admitted to assign default values to parameters in a function:

***NOT OK***

```
/* .h */
class FooClass(){

   public:
      void foofunc(int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4);
}

/* .cpp */
FooClass::foofunc(int var1, int var2)
    : var3(0), var4(5)
{
     //whatever function does...
}
```

which must instead be done like this:

***OK***

```
/* .h */
class FooClass(){

   public:
      void foofunc(int var1, int var2, int var3 = 0, int var4 = 5);
}

/* .cpp */
FooClass::foofunc(int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4)
{
     //whatever function does...
}
```

Why?

Comment: why have you voted for closing?

Comment: Neither your second nor third example are valid, because the declaration and definition don't match. If you made the same number of parameters, then either way would be valid.

Comment: @peachykeen first of all third example is ok, I made a copy/paste mistake but who answered understood my point. Second thing if in my second example (***marked with not ok cause I know it's not correct***) I put the same number of parameters it would still not work because of my confusion with initialization lists in constructors. And making mistakes in a question shouldn't be a good reason to vote for closing it.

Comment: I never mentioned your first example for exactly that reason. Your second one, with the correct parameters, *would* have worked. The vote was not mine, although I have since voted to close because the question shows no research effort; half the code isn't even vaguely valid, but not because of the issue at hand, but because the functions are written incorrectly wrt how parameters work.

Comment: @peachykeen I would like to know how you judge effort, still I believe that it may be a good reason for down voting, not for closing a question.

Comment: The problem in this case is that the given code samples all have different problems, showing a misunderstanding of basic language structure, and making a) the stated question not the problem at hand and b) difficult to answer the stated question because valid code would change the answer (the latter being on the list of reasons to close).

Comment: @peachykeen I still disagree: when I posted the question users were able to answer and helped me understand the problem (which I think might be a quite general misunderstanding to people not as expert as you). Never mind though. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example isn't one of "default values" at all - that is an [initialisation list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) for the members and bases of the object, which only makes sense in a constructor. Constructors can however have default argument values, using the same syntax as for any other function.

So this is fine, for example:

```
explicit FooClass(int* data = NULL, int depth = 0, int rows = 0, int columns = 0, char* desc = NULL)
    : data(data), depth(depth), rows(rows), columns(columns), desc(desc)
{
}
```

If you need more than just simple default values for any kind of function, consider overloading the function, e.g.:

```
void my_function(int a, int b)
{
    // do stuff with a and b
}

void my_function()
{
    // version with no arguments, "default" behaviour
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is initializing class members or parent classes; the function is setting default values for its parameters.

Comment: and so there is no other way to set default values in functions?and suppose I call function wanting default value for variable 3 but specifying value for variable 4 how will compiler understand?

Comment: You can't.  You can only omit a variable (and use its default value) if you've omitted all subsequent variables in the parameter list.

Comment: If the 3rd and 4th argument are of sufficiently different types, you could consider overloading the function, with a version of the function where the 3rd argument is missing. If you're not careful, this can lead to a confusing API though. If the 3rd argument has a sensible default, but the 4th doesn't, consider swapping their positions.